# Column intersection multiple python lists

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose, you have a list of lists as follows:

```
A = [
     [(1, 9), (2, 10), (3, 11), (4, 12), (5, 13), (6, 14), (7, 15), (8, 16)], 
     [(1, 19), (2, 110), (13, 1), (41, 112), (51, 131), (16, 141), (17, 15), (18, 16)],
     [(1, 299), (2, 1310), (13, 111), (41, 112), (51, 131), (16, 141), (17, 15), (18, 16)]
    ]
```

What I am looking for is the fastest way of finding the intersection over one of the columns of the existing tuples within the list. For instance, If I need to find the column intersection over x0 where each sublist comprises of (x0, x1) then the output should be:

```
out = [(1,9), (1,19), (2, 10), (2, 110), (1, 299), (2, 1310)]
```

which is basically a set of all the elements having value of the first column  similar.

The approach I am using to find a plain intersection to match the entire tuple is basically (it gives out complete matches from all the sub lists):

```
out = set.intersection(*map(set, A))
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: How exactly did you get that result?  Are you saying you want to find cases where there is a number `x` so that each list contains a tuple of the form `(x, y)`?

Comment: yes. like, each sublist contains tuples of the form (x, y) so what I need is to find all the tuples where (lets say) x is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Three steps:

1) Make a list of sets of the *x0* elements.

2) Find the intersection of those steps.

3) Lastly, make a list of all *(x0, x1)* pairs where *x0* is in the set of overlaps.

Here's how:

```
>>> first_elems = [{x0 for x0, x1 in sublist} for sublist in A]
>>> overlaps = set.intersection(*first_elems)
>>> [(x0, x1) for sublist in A for x0, x1 in sublist if x0 in overlaps]
[(1, 9), (2, 10), (1, 19), (2, 110), (1, 299), (2, 1310)]
```

Answer (score 0):

okay.. I came up with something..here it is:

```
out = []

for aa in A:
   out.append([b for b in aa if b[0] in set.intersection(*map(set, [r[:, 0] for r in numpy.array(A)]))])


out = [[(1, 9), (2, 10)], [(1, 19), (2, 110)], [(1, 299), (2, 1310)]]
out = [u for v in out for u in v]
```

Now, i should be comparing speeds b/w this and @Raymond's answer. :-)  many thanks.